# How to get CloudWatch to send an alarm every time a threshold has been breached?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, alarm, amazon-cloudwatch

Currently using this script to monitor:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html

When the script is first run we receive the email, but after that the email never sends (even though the threshold has been breached continuously).

Comment: You want it to keep sending emails every time the metric is updated? Most people don't want to get a duplicate email every 5 minutes. You generally get an alert email and assume the alert is ongoing until you receive another email that the metric has fallen below the threshold.

Comment: It's plausible that we'll miss an email though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amazon CloudWatch alarms **will only trigger notifications when the state of the Alarm changes**. It will *not* continuously send alarms when the state is Alert and it is not possible to configure such behavior.

One exception to this is triggering Auto Scaling changes -- it will continually try to trigger an Auto Scaling policy while the state is in Alarm.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example of a custom metrics that reset itself `every hour`: [Custom CloudWatch metrics with hourly reset](https://github.com/imriss/aws_factory/tree/master/p1_cloudwatch_custom). Therefore, the notifications are also repeated every hour, if the alarm has not been resolved.