# AWS CloudWatch alarm keeps sending mails for as long as evaluation interval lasts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm

I've set up an AWS CloudWatch alarm with the following parameters:

```
ActionsEnabled: true
AlarmActions: "some SNS topic"
AlarmDescription: "Too many HTTP 5xx errors"
ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
DatapointsToAlarm: 1
Dimensions:
  - Name: ApiName
    Value: "some API"
EvaluationPeriods: 20
MetricName: 5XXError
Namespace: AWS/ApiGateway
Period: 300
Statistic: Average
Threshold: 0.1
TreatMissingData: ignore
```

The idea is to receive a mail when there are too many HTTP 500 errors. I believe the above gives me an alarm that evaluates time periods of 5 minutes (300s). If 1 out of 20 data points exceeds the limit (10% of the requests) I should receive an email.

This works. I receive the email. But even if the amount of errors drops below the threshold again, I seem to keep receiving emails. It seems to be more or less for the entire duration of the evaluation interval (1h40min = 20 x 5 minutes). Also, I receive these mails every 5 minutes, leading me to think there must be a connection with my configuration.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086402/how-to-get-cloudwatch-to-send-an-alarm-every-time-a-threshold-has-been-breached) implies that this shouldn't happen, which seems logical to me. In fact, I'd expect not to receive an email for at least 1 hour and 40 minutes (20 x 5 minutes), even if the threshold is breached again.

This is the graph of my metric/alarm:
[image: AWS CloudWatch Alarm]

Correction: I actually received 22 mails.

Have I made an error in my configuration?

**Update**
I can see that the state is set from Alarm to OK 3 minutes after it was set from OK to Alarm:

[image: Alarm state changes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what we've found and how we fixed it.

So we're evaluating blocks of 5 minutes and taking the average of the amount of errors. But AWS is evaluating at faster intervals than 5 minutes. The distribution of your errors can be such that at a given point in time, a 5 minute block has an average of 12%. But a bit later, this block could be split in two giving you two blocks with different averages, possibly lower than the threshold.

That's what we **believe** is going on.

We've fixed it by changing our Period to 60s, and change our DatapointsToAlarm and EvaluationPeriods settings.